# браузер не видит функцию $.modal не смотря на то что она есть, ошибка: "Uncaught TypeError: $.modal is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function _CreateModal(options) {
  const modal = document.createElement(tagName: 'div')
  modal.classList.add('vmodal')
  modal.insertAdjacentHTML(where: 'afterbegin', html: ` 
       <div class = "modal-overlay">
        <div class = "modal-window">
         <div class = "modal-header">
          <span class = "modal-title">
           Some title      
          </span>
          <span class = "modal-close">
           &times;      
          </span>
         </div>     
         <div class = "modal-body">     
          <p>lorem100</p>
          <p>lorem100</p>
         </div>     
         <div class = "modal-footer">
          <button>OK</button>
          <button>Cansel</button>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      `)
  document.body.appendChild(modal)
  return :modal
}
$.modal = function(options) {
  const $modal = _CreateModal(options)
  return {
    open() {},
    close() {},
    destroy() {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Я начал изучать js два дня назад, поэтому объясните свою точку зрения как можно конкретней, заранее спасибо

Comment: Не знаю где там $.modal, но это то зачем `return :modal` с двоеточием

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg, а как вызывается `modal.insertAdjacentHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже писали ранее, у вас несколько синтаксических ошибок. Ниже представлен корректный фрагмент вашего кода:

```
function _CreateModal(options) {
    const modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.classList.add('vmodal');
    modal.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
      <div class="modal-overlay">
        <div class="modal-window">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="modal-title">
              Some title                        
            </span>
            <span class="modal-close">
              &times;                       
            </span>
          </div>                    
          <div class="modal-body">                  
            <p>lorem100</p>
            <p>lorem100</p>
          </div>                    
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button>OK</button>
            <button>Cansel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
    document.body.appendChild(modal);
    return modal;
};
$.modal = function(options) {
    const $modal = _CreateModal(options);
    return {
        open() {},
        close() {},
        destroy() {}
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Такого синтаксиса -

```
const modal = document.createElement(tagName: 'div')
```

в JavaScript нет. А такой -

```
const modal = document.createElement('div')
```

есть.

Названия параметров - это подсказки редактора. Aвтор видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX2fiUvrYP4&t=1631s их не печатает.

Comment: Спасибо что заметили, но проблему это никак не решило

Comment: @викторчернов Проблему это решило. Просто Вам надо исправить это везде. Сейчас в Вашем коде синтактические ошибки. Когда парсер на них натыкается, он выбрасывает весь блок кода, как будто его нет. Поэтому и функции Вашей не существует.

Comment: Мой код полностью переписан из этого видео:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX2fiUvrYP4&t=1631s 27-ая минута

Comment: @викторчернов Ха-ха-ха! Названия параметров - это подсказки редактора. Если бы Вы были повнимательнее, Вы бы заметили, что автор их не печатает. Читайте книги.