# браузер не видит функцию $.modal не смотря на то что она есть

Tags: javascript, html

Расставлять точки с запятой уже пробовал, не помогло. Код взят из этого видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX2fiUvrYP4&t=1631s , 27-ая минута

```js
function _CreateModal(options) {
  const modal = document.createElement(tagName: 'div')
  modal.classList.add('vmodal')
  modal.insertAdjacentHTML(where: 'afterbegin', html: ` 
               <div class = "modal-overlay">
                <div class = "modal-window">
                 <div class = "modal-header">
                  <span class = "modal-title">
                   Some title      
                  </span>
                  <span class = "modal-close">
                   &times;      
                  </span>
                 </div>     
                 <div class = "modal-body">     
                  <p>lorem100</p>
                  <p>lorem100</p>
                 </div>     
                 <div class = "modal-footer">
                  <button>OK</button>
                  <button>Cansel</button>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              `)
  document.body.appendChild(modal)
  return :modal
}
$.modal = function(options) {
  const $modal = _CreateModal(options)
  return {
    open() {},
    close() {},
    destroy() {}
  }
}
```

Я начал изучать js два дня назад, поэтому объясните свою точку зрения как можно конкретней, заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125231 - Я уже ответил Вам на этот вопрос (с объяснением в чем дело) до того, как Вы начали мне хамить.